# Place a button inside a grid

Tags: python, wxpython

In a gui I have a grid. In this grid each row represents an order. To the right of each row, I would like to place a 'cancel button'to cancel the order. When new rows are added this should automatically come with a cancel button.
I did some seaching but apart from [this FAQ-question](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions#How_do_I_render_buttons_in_a_wxGrid.3F/) which states that you have to design something yourself (did not help me much). Al other material was based on usage of Tkinter which I do not want to do.
So Two questions:
(1) Does anyone know of a way to place a button in a grid cell in wxpython?
(2) If not, does anyone know of a solution for my requirement?
Thanks,
Django

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a "built-in" way to do this. You would need to create a custom Renderer. According to Robin Dunn (creator of wxPython) in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/HhtKCxPVX_s), you could create a button using wx.RendererNative.DrawPushButton.

I would also recommend taking a look at the wxPython demo as it has some other examples of custom renderers too.